# Prime Number Generator in C++ always includes 4 and 9

Tags: c++

I used this code for generating primes to a certain value the user inputs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    bool prime = true;
    int i, j, k, input;
    cout << "Number to test until: ";
    cin >> input;
    for (i = 2; i <= input; i++) {
        prime = true;
        j = ceil(sqrt(i));
        for (k = 2; k < j; k++) {
            if (i % k == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            cout << i << " is prime\n";
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the output for the primes always includes 4 and 9, even though they would have been removed since the square root of 4 is 2, and 2 % 2 = 0.

Comment: Do you know in what order the increment and comparison are executed?

Comment: Debug your code. Print all intermediate results for i=4.

Comment: Try with `k <= j`. And don't do this: `int i, j, k, input;`

Comment: It seems to be printing 4 continuously

Comment: Voted to close as simple typo.

Comment: Use more sophisticated names than i, j, k to make it easier to read and to find errors..

Comment: I recommend starting the loop at 3 and incrementing by 2.  That cuts out half of the possible checks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @LogicStuff mentioned. This should work:

```
    for (k = 2; k <= j; k++) 
    { 
        // ..
    }
```